# Unit vectors that are orthogonal to vectors

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vectors, orthogonality, cross-product

I have to find all the unit vectors that are orthogonal to the vectors $\overrightarrow{a}=(2, -4, 3), \overrightarrow{b}=(-4, 8, -6)$ .

I calculated that the cross product $\overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{b}=0$.

Does this mean that the vector $(0, 0, 0)$ is a unit vector that is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$ ??

Comment: No, $(0,0,0)$ is never a unit vector. A zero cross product means that $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are parallel (and indeed $\vec b=-2\vec a$), so anything that is perpendicular to one will be perpendicular to the other too.

Comment: Ok... How can we find ALL the unit vectors that are orthogonal to the vectors?? @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{a}=(2, -4, 3), \vec{b}=(-4, 8, -6)$ are elements of $\Bbb R^3$.  Notice that $\vec b = -2\vec a$, thus the two vectors are collinear.  So the space of vectors that are orthogonal the both of these vectors will just be the space of vectors orthogonal to the line that passes through both of them.  Can you see that this space will be a plane?

So you just need to specify a plane with a vector equation.  The vector equation of a plane is $\vec r(s,t) = \vec us + \vec vt + \vec c$.

We just need to find any two non-collinear vectors orthogonal to $\vec a$ or $\vec b$ (any we find orthogonal to one will automatically be orthogonal to the other).

So we need $(x,y,z) \cdot (2,-4,3) = 2x-4y+3z=0$.  Being a linear equation in three variables, we should just be able to choose two of the variables and solve for the last (though don't choose them both zero or you'll just end up with the zero vector which is collinear with *every* other vector).  Let's choose $x=3$ and $y=0$.  Plugging in, we see that $z=-2$.  So one vector orthogonal to $(2,-4,3)$ is $(3,0,-2)$.  Now let's choose $x=0$ and $y=3$ (You could choose the the two numbers to be whatever you like, but notice I chose them so that I'd get integer solutions because no one likes unnecessary fractions).  Then $z=4$.  So another vector orthogonal to $(2,-4,3)$ is $(0,3,4)$.  Notice that $(3,0,-2)$ and $(0,3,4)$ are not collinear (they are not scalar multiples of each other).

So let $\vec u=(3,0,-2)$ and $\vec v=(0,3,4)$.  Then to find $\vec c$ we need any point on the line $\operatorname{span}(2,-4,3)$.  $(0,0,0)$ is in that span.  So let $\vec c = \vec 0$.

Then the equation representing our plane -- and thus *every* vector orthogonal to $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ -- is just $$\vec r(s,t) = (3,0,-2)s + (0,3,4)t$$

Comment: I see!! Thank you!!! :-)

Comment: I read again your answer and I got stuck... The space of vectors that are orthogonal to both of the vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is the space of vectors orthogonal to the line that passes through both of them, because this line is parallel to both vectors, right? Why is this space a plane? Why is the vector equation equal to $\vec r(s,t) = \vec us + \vec vt + \vec c$ ?

Comment: $\vec b = -2\vec a$ so $\vec b$ and $\vec a$ are parallel to each other.  Thus *any* vector perpendicular to one will be perpendicular to the other.  This means that we really one need to consider the set of vectors orthogonal to *one* of those two vectors.  That set of vectors has a special name -- the **orthogonal complement** of the line $\operatorname{span}(\vec a)$ (or $\vec b$ since they're parallel).  Go back and look through your linear algebra text (or Google it) to see some of the properties of the orthogonal complement.  Most importantly are the properties that the orthogonal...

Comment: complement of a subspace is a subspace and that if $W^{\perp}$ is the orthogonal complement of $W$ in the vector space $V$ then $W+W^{\perp} = V$ (assuming finite dimension).  Therefore the space orthogonal to $\vec a$ (and $\vec b$) will be a vector space of dimension $2$ -- i.e. a plane.  The equation $\vec r(s,t) = \vec us + \vec vt +\vec c$ is the standard (vector) equation of a plane.

Comment: Now, something I forgot to mention when I wrote this answer is that because you're just looking for the unit length vectors orthogonal to your pair of vectors, you'll have to restrict the plane to only the vectors of unit length -- i.e. you'll have to specify the unit circle of the plane $\vec r = \vec r(s,t)$.

Comment: I haven't really understood how you concluded that the space orthogonal to a is a vector space of dimension 2. Could you explain it further to me? Why isn't the equation of the plane of the form $ax+by+cz+d=0$ ?

Comment: Consider the standard basis of $\Bbb R^3$: $\{i,j,k\}$.  What are all of the vectors orthogonal to, say, $j$?  Hopefully you can see in that case that it's just the $ik$-plane.  Now rotate those three vectors until they are not aligned with the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-axes.  Clearly the set of vectors orthogonal to the new $j'$ vector is still the span of the other two vectors: $i'$ and $k'$.  So in $3$D the set of vectors orthogonal to a given vector is the span of $2$ vectors -- a plane.

Comment: $\vec r(s,t) = \vec us + \vec vt +\vec c$ is the standard **vector** equation of a plane and $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is the standard **scalar** equation of a plane.  Both describe the same object, they just do it in terms of different things -- the vector equation tells you which vectors span your plane and the scalar equation (which only works in $3$D and is thus less general) describes the plane as the space orthogonal to a given *normal* vector: $(a,b,c)$.  The problem with the scalar equation in this case is that it's not immediately apparent to me how to pick out the unit length subset.

Answer (score 1):

No, $(0, 0, 0)$ is not a unit vector (it has $0$ length).

Note that $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are parallel, so the vectors perpendicular to $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are in the plane perpendicular to $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: How can we find ALL the unit vectors that are orthogonal to the vectors??

Answer (score 1):

Nope. In this case, it means that $a$ and $b$ are parallel vectors. :)

Comment: How can we find all the unit vectors that are orthogonal to the vectors??

Comment: As Abel notes, $\mathbf v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}(3, 0, 2)$ is one such vector. Taking the cross product with $(2, -4, 3)$ and normalizing gives $\mathbf  w = \frac{1}{\sqrt{233}} (8, -5, -12)$, and $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ are perpendicular, just like the unit vectors on the $x$- and $y$-axes of the plane. If you form all cosine/sine combinations of these (i.e., $\cos(t) \mathbf v + \sin(t) \mathbf w$), you get all possible unit vectors perpendicular to the ones given in your problem.

Comment: Ok... Thanks!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has pointed out, $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are parallel, so we only need to use one of them. Using $\mathbf{a}$,  the vecotrs orthogonal to it are all vectors $(x,y,z)$ such that $2x-4y+3z=0$. We can eliminate one of these variables, say $x$, so all the orthogonal vectors are those of the form $(2y-\frac{3}{2}z, y, z)$.

To make them unit vectors, you can divide by their length, which is $\sqrt{(2y-\frac{3}{2}z)^2 + y^2 +z^2}$.

So all the orthogonal unit vectors are the vectors of the form $$\frac{(2y-\frac{3}{2}z, y, z)}{\sqrt{(2y-\frac{3}{2}z)^2 + y^2 +z^2}}$$

Comment: In that way do we find ALL the unit vectors that are orthogonal to the vectors??

Comment: In this case the cross product _is_ zero, because the two vectors are parallel.

Comment: The cross product is the zero *vector*, not the number $0$.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

suppose $(x, y, z)$ is orthogonal to $(2,-4,3).$ then the dot product $2x-4y+3z = 0$ 
two nonzero solutions are $(3, 0, -2)$ and $(2,1,0).$ any combination of the two vectors is also orthogonal to $(2,-4,3).$  to make a nonzero vector unit length, just divide by its length. for example the length of $(3,0, -2)$ is $\sqrt{3^2 + (-2)^2} = \sqrt {13}$ so that $(3/\sqrt{13}, 0, -2/\sqrt{13})$ is a unit vector.

$\bf edit:$

to find all the unit vectors, we need to find an orthogonal basis first. if you project $(3,0,-2)$ onto $(2,1,0)$ you get $(4,2,0).$ that is we have split $(3,0,-2) = (4,2,0) + (-1,2,-2).$  therefore an orthogonal basis is $\{(2,1,0), (-1,2,-2)\}.$ we make them orthonormal by dividing by their lengths so that $$\{u = (2/\sqrt 5, 1/\sqrt 5), v = (-1/3, 2/3, 2/3)\}$$ 
finally, an arbitrary unit orthogoanal vector is $$u\cos t + v \sin t, t \text{ any real number.}$$

Comment: Do we find, in that way, ALL all the unit vectors that are orthogonal to the vectors ??

Comment: you do find all vectors orthogonal as the linear combinations of the two vectors in the post. they are linearly independent, so it is a basis for the space orthogonal to the line $(2t, -4t, 3t)$

Comment: @MaryStar, i have updated my post to give a better answer to your question. check it out.

Comment: Ok... Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As another approach, solve the system $<a,x>=0,$ using the standard Euclidean inner product i.e $2x_1 -4x_2+3x_3=0.$ This equation has two free variables, so it defines a plane, which is exactly what you would expect working in $\mathbb R^3.$ In case you don't know, a free variable means you can choose any value for it. So make two separate sets of choices, and the span of the two solutions is the plane you seek.

For more information, I'd consult an introductory linear algebra text.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!!! :-)